# Functional way to Wrap multiple methods into one

Tags: java, function, optimization, functional-programming, kotlin

I am fairly new to the World of Function style Programming I was trying some code in Kotlin, given snippet below is what I did, but Looks so much Imperative to me

```
@EmailTemplate("onCallTemplate")
fun retrieveNextOnCallCreateMailRecipientAndSendMail(time: LocalDateTime, trial: Boolean = true) {

    val emailTemplateID =
            extractEmailTemplateValue(
                    "retrieveNextOnCallAndSendMail")

    val messageTemplate = emailTemplateID?.let { messageTemplateAccessPoint.findByID(it) }


    val lisOfOnCalls = dataHubCommunicator
            .listOfOnCallToSendNotificationFromDataHub(time)

    val listOfMailRecipient = lisOfOnCalls
            ?.let { onCallListToMailRecipient.buildMailRecipientFromOnCalls(it) }


    listOfMailRecipient
            ?.let {
                messageTemplate
                        ?.let { it1 ->
                            emailSender
                                    .sendNotificationToOnCallPersons(it, it1, trial)
                        }
            }

    log.info("Message Has been sent Successfully")

}
```

this function works like an aggregator it retrieves and invokes corresponding values/states from other functions.
What I don't like about this method is declaring the variable(val/var) everywhere to store the values to pass on other methods.

I cannot do this either for sake of readability

```
onCallListToMailRecipient.buildMailRecipientFromOnCalls(dataHubCommunicator
    .listOfOnCallToSendNotificationFromDataHub(time))
```

Is there any declarative way to write this method.What changes can I do to make it more declarative/functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge a few computations and reduce the number of local vars. Also, the last sequence of two `let` is rather useless, simply call the function with your local variables. I added some `null` checks instead.

```
val messageTemplate = extractEmailTemplateValue("retrieveNextOnCallAndSendMail")?.let {
    messageTemplateAccessPoint.findByID(it) 
} ?: throw IllegalStateException (“Todo”)

val listOfMailRecipient = dataHubCommunicator.listOfOnCallToSendNotificationFromDataHub(time)?.let { 
    onCallListToMailRecipient.buildMailRecipientFromOnCalls(it) 
} ?: throw IllegalStateException (“Todo”)

emailSender
    .sendNotificationToOnCallPersons(listOfMailRecipient, messageTemplate, trial).also{
    println("Message Has been sent Successfully")
}
```

Comment: Removing the let after `messageTemplate` causes `sendNotificationToOnCallPersons` to be called if `messageTemplate` is null, so it's not the same.

Comment: @HankD the nullability cases are ignored and not handled at all, I don’t think that’s the desired behaviour,

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
fun retrieveNextOnCallCreateMailRecipientAndSendMail(time: LocalDateTime, trial: Boolean = true) {
    doWithListOfMail(time) { l ->
        doWithTemplate('retrieveNextOnCallAndSendMail') { t ->
            emailSender.sendNotificationToOnCallPersons(l, t, trial)
        }
    }
    log.info("Message Has been sent Successfully")
}
fun doWithTemplate(id: String, action: (Template) -> Void){
    val emailTemplateID = extractEmailTemplateValue(id)
    val messageTemplate = emailTemplateID?.let { 
        messageTemplateAccessPoint.findByID(it) 
    }
    messageTemplate?.let(action)    
}
fun doWithListOfMail(time : LocalDateTime, action: (List) -> Void) {
    val lisOfOnCalls = dataHubCommunicator
        .listOfOnCallToSendNotificationFromDataHub(time)
    val listOfMailRecipient = lisOfOnCalls?.let {
        onCallListToMailRecipient.buildMailRecipientFromOnCalls(it) 
    }
    listOfMailRecipient?.let(action)
}
```

Comment: a true functional approach.

Answer (score 1):

You might omit the val temporary variables when they are only used in the next statement, using `let` on each successive line instead. Applying that rule of thumb, your example might look like:

```
val messageTemplate = extractEmailTemplateValue("retrieveNextOnCallAndSendMail")
    ?.let(messageTemplateAccessPoint::findByID)

dataHubCommunicator.listOfOnCallToSendNotificationFromDataHub(time)
    ?.let(onCallListToMailRecipient::buildMailRecipientFromOnCalls)
    ?.let {
        messageTemplate?.let {
            emailSender.sendNotificationToOnCallPersons(it, messageTemplate, trial)
        }
    }
```

It may not be more readable, but it is less bulky.

Answer (score 1):

Things may depend on nullity for some of these, if you like the `let` family you can do something like this as well:

```
fun retrieveNextOnCallCreateMailRecipientAndSendMail(time: LocalDateTime, trial: Boolean = true) =
    dataHubCommunicator
        .listOfOnCallToSendNotificationFromDataHub(time)
        .let {
            onCallListToMailRecipient.buildMailRecipientFromOnCalls(it)
        }
        .apply {
            val template = messageTemplateAccessPoint.findByID(
                    extractEmailTemplateValue("retrieveNextOnCallAndSendMail"))

            emailSender.sendNotificationToOnCallPersons(this, template, trial)
        }
        .also {
            log.info("Message has been sent successfully to ${it}")
        }
        // if you have nullable recipient and want to detect failure
        // ?: log.info("Message not sent")
```

Note: new lines in blocks help for IDEA to show hints, so you get the automatic variables + some free type information:
[image: IDEA hints]

Notes: in general I would hold back on the `?.` is everything really nullable around there? If we need to specify `it1` to distinguish from `it` because of nesting might as well take the opportunity to name the variable nicely.

Appendix of declaration stubs for type safety testing (I assumed non-null, but questionmarks can be added wherever):

```
interface OnCall
interface MessageTemplate
interface MessageTemplateID
interface MailRecipient
interface MessageTemplateAccessPoint {
    fun findByID(it: MessageTemplateID): MessageTemplate
}

interface DataHubCommunicator {
    fun listOfOnCallToSendNotificationFromDataHub(time: LocalDateTime): List<OnCall>
}

interface OnCallListToMailRecipient {
    fun buildMailRecipientFromOnCalls(oncalls: List<OnCall>): MailRecipient
}

interface EmailSender {
    fun sendNotificationToOnCallPersons(recipient: MailRecipient, template: MessageTemplate, trial: Boolean)
}

fun extractEmailTemplateValue(name: String): MessageTemplateID = TODO()

val dataHubCommunicator: DataHubCommunicator = TODO()
val messageTemplateAccessPoint: MessageTemplateAccessPoint = TODO()
val onCallListToMailRecipient: OnCallListToMailRecipient = TODO()
val emailSender: EmailSender = TODO()
```